# file is not a zip file error but I am not opening a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a BCT trading bot.  I am pulling data in from the API from my exchange.  I am saving the data in files like btc_10Xave_timestamp().
I have another script that is analyzing this data.  These files are produced every 100 trades regardless of trade size.  Every so often I combine them into a master file of data.  The issue that I am having is with this analyzer.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob, time
from playsound import playsound

print('Monitoring for time to trade...')
while True:
    try:
        previous_time = 0.0
        time_of_file = 0.0
        sum_size = 0.0
        last_price = 0.0
        previous_price = 0.0
        files_array = np.sort(glob.glob('btc*.xlsx'))

        if len(glob.glob('btc*.xlsx')) > 1:

            df = pd.read_excel(files_array[-1], header=None)
            sum_size = df.iloc[:,2].sum()
            last_price = df.iloc[-1, 1]

            previous_df = pd.read_excel(files_array[-2], header=None)
            previous_price = previous_df.iloc[-1, 1]

            diff_price = last_price - previous_price

            previous_time = files_array[-2]    [11:files_array[0].index('.xlsx')-1]

            last_time = files_array[-1][11:files_array[0].index('.xlsx')-1]
            time_lapse = str(float(last_time) - float(previous_time))


            if float(time_lapse) < 10:
                #volumne is rapidly moving in at this point
                if diff_price > 0:
                    #buying opp
                    playsound('golong.mp3')
                    print('Buying Opportunity Here @: $'+   str(last_time))
                    print("Last 100 trades of : " + str(sum_size) + " BTC in " + time_lapse + " seconds.")
                    print("This volumne moved the market " +str(diff_price) + " USD")
                elif diff_price < 0:
                    #sell opp
                    playsound('sellit.mp3')
                    print('Selling Opportunity Here @: $' + str(last_time))
                    print("Last 100 trades of : " + str(sum_size) + " BTC in " + time_lapse + " seconds.")
                    print("This volumne moved the market " +str(diff_price) + " USD")
                else:
                    pass
        time.sleep(10)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Again the error that is being thrown says: "file is not a zip file"
I am totally confused as to how or why this happening.
From the appearance of this code it is simple enough.  I have no idea where the source of error is.  Any insight is of course appreciated.  Thank you to all you awesome coders out there!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback of the error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Among other things, we need the *entire* error message (including traceback), and superfluous code removed.

Comment: OK I edited the code with the traceback and logging packages.  I reran the code, I have to wait for the error to hit again and I will share if I can not find solution.  Thanks alot thus far.

Answer (score 1):

XSLX files are ZIP files internally. You can unpack XLSX files with [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.de/) for example. Perhaps the file you want to open is not a XLSX file but a XLS file (old office file format) instead or something totally unrelated.

It seems you are looking for new files continuously with

```
glob.glob('btc*.xlsx')
```

It's possible that you found a new file but that file has not been fully written yet. This could be improved by waiting the 10 seconds after a new file was found (though, just waiting an arbitrary time will not resolve the issue 100%)

> There is no stack trace. The only error is that. It says "file is not a zip file" and it repeats in an infinite loop because of the while loop.

There is no stack trace, because you catch the exception and only print its message. Use

```
traceback.print_exc()
```

to print the last exception, or, even better, don't catch the exception.

Comment: It is an xlsx file. Im waiting for the error to hit again this time with the traceback. Thanks alot Thomas!

Comment: is there a way to test if file is completely written to or not because that sounds like that might be the issue.  Is there a better solution?  Maybe to use listdir() or os.walk implementations?